# How to push a new view controller from a view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I created a view in .xib. On it, I placed a button on which I want to open another ViewController. I assigned a storyboardID to this ViewController. But I can't push the new controller, how can this problem be solved?

My code:

```
class MyView: UIView {
...
   @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "ViewController", bundle: Bundle.init())
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC") as! ViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController.init()
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }
...
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
...
}
```

Xcode gives this error:

> 'Could not find a storyboard named' ViewController'

but I checked there are no errors. I reloaded Xcode - no result.

Comment: you cant push from UIView ...

Comment: you need to ask the controller in which UIView is residing

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: where you are using `MyView` ?

Comment: In a TableViewController

Comment: you need to push from that `TableViewController`

Comment: What is the name of your storyboard?

Comment: I must use delegate?

Comment: My storyboard name is ViewController (full ViewController.storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have more than one issue.

1. You are trying to push a `UIViewController` into a non presented `UINavigationController`
2. You are creating an instance from a `UIStoryboard` with wrong identifier

First you need to choose the correct `UIStoryboard` which I am assuming it's **main**, then you have to present the `UINavigationController` from the holder `UIViewController` or trying to push from that `UIViewController` if it's has a `UINavigationController`,

Part 1: Fixing the instances,

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "main", bundle: Bundle())
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC") as! ViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
```

Now you have a `navigationController` that holds a your `VC`

Part 2: You want to present this navigation from your holding `VC` you can either add a listener to the `UIButton` from that `VC` and present/push from there

so lets wrap this up create a function in your `VC` that holds the `UIView`

```
@objc func pushToMyVc() {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "main", bundle: Bundle())
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC") as! ViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
}
```

And in your `UIView` add this variable `var selector: (() -> Void)?`

Now in `@IBAction func buttonPressed` call this function `selector?()`

Now all we need is to pass what function I want to use when this button gets clicked in our case the function `pushToMyVC` that we put in our main `UIViewController` so in our `didLoad` or wherever you're calling this custom view

set the selector like this

```
myView.selector = pushtoMyVC
```

> Side Note: you can't present/push `UIViewController` from non
> `UIViewController` classes

Comment: There are several storyboards in my project, I do not use the main storyboard, but work through the code. For the ViewController, I created a separate storyboard, in this storyboard I added a NavigationController for the ViewController

Comment: use the storyboard that holds the `vc` that you want to present. use the file name

Comment: if the storyboard name `viewcontroller` I recommend you to change it to something else

Comment: Should I add in the func @objc func pushToMyVc() { ...navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)}?

Comment: I did as you said, but for some reason nothing happens when the button is pressed. I use this code myView.selector = pushtoMyVC in my TableViewController (who hold UIView) in didSelectRow func, does it right?

Comment: it's not gonna work from didSelectRow, you need to either place from where you create it's instance, and try to debug it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219176/discussion-between-vyacheslavb-and-mohmmad-s).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing how you fetch the storyboard from

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "ViewController", bundle: Bundle.init())
```

to

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
```

note that the storyboard ID needs to be exactly `ViewController`.

If this still shows the same error, I'd say you have an issue with the storyboard target membership, so check that in the file inspector on the right side of the Xcode editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Storyboard file name again, because when you want to initiate a `UIViewController` from a Storyboard file, the `name` parameter in `UIStoryboard` initiation has to be exactly the same as the Storyboard file name.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Let's say that you have a Storyboard file named ViewController.storyboard and a UIViewController class named ViewController.swift
    let destinationVC = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC") as! ViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
}
```

Hope this helps your issue

Answer (score -1):

you should take a delegate back to viewController that contains current view, and call navigationController.push from there